# Wordpress admin login page inaccessible?

Tags: wordpress

I get the following error when I try to access Wordpress admin login page of my client's site:

```
Sorry, your request cannot be accepted.
```

It opens for my client though. The client has not blocked my IP, or my country, then why is it happening?

Here is the [wp-admin area](https://tsmagency.com/wp-admin/). Does the page open for you?

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick investigation, it looks like the issue is spawning from the plugin you have installed called IP Geo Block. https://wordpress.org/plugins/ip-geo-block/

I'd recommend disabling this plugin temporarily and attempting to login. If you're still having issues, it's worth creating a support ticket with that plugin maker.